# Custom Refinable Filters on on-prem SharePoint page in hybrid search

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, sharepoint-on-prem, refinement-panel, hybrid-search

I have configured hybrid cloud search between SP 2013 and SP Online. I was able to get the online and on-prem from the on-prem search page by configuring new result source (Remote SharePoint).

Now, I want to configure the custom refiners on the on-prem search page. I don't see the refiners which were configured under online search schema.

Do I need to setup anything specific to refiners in hybrid search settings or this is a drawback in cloud hybrid search?

Can someone give me a push on this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have configured Refinable*NN, simply re-use that refiner (e.g. RefinableString01) in your refiner. The Cloud Search Service will use the SPO schema to determine what that refiner is for.

Comment: The refinable properties working as expected if I use in the search query. I am looking for the refiners under refiners webpart on a on-prem search page. If we assume the Refinablestring** will show under refiners webpart in online I see there are 200 refinablestring properties but in on-prem I see only 100 refinablestring. If user choose above 100 it won`t show up again.